# Script Counts up by 2 instead of 1

Tags: php, count

I have a count.php script that counts the number of refreshes on my site. The code for it is this:

```
if (file_exists('countlog.txt')) 
{
    $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('countlog.txt')); 
    echo $dat+1;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
}

else
{
    $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
}
```

The issue is that when I try to run it, it always count's as two. I have tried to edit the: `echo $dat+1` to just `echo $dat` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help?

Comment: What is `echo $dat+1` showing you?  Are you seeing *multiple* echos?  So, the value in the *file* is incremented twice?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it shows me the value. I only see one echo responded. The value in the file is increased twice. I compared what I see to what the countlog.txt says and they are both the same. I have it running on my website @ http://abs0rb.ml on the right saying Total Visits. It always counts up by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error_resporting on? I think not.

Try to:

```
if (file_exists('countlog.txt')) 
    {
        $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', 'r');
        $dat = fread($fil, filesize('countlog.txt')); 
        echo $dat+1;
        fclose($fil);
        $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
    }

    else
    {
        $fil = fopen('countlog.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fil, 1);
        echo '1';
        fclose($fil);
    }
```

Check this: `('countlog.txt', 'w')`you missed the 'w'.

The error that outputs if you miss the single quote ' is this:

**Notice: Use of undefined constant r - assumed 'r'**